# How to show audit data in the front end as timeline when user adds,modifies,deletes etc

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, rest, jakarta-ee, spring-data

Single Page Application which is developed in angular JS. I Just wanted to know the audit of the user activity in the front end timeline based on the users interaction with the database.

The database layer is done using HIBERNATE and controller layer with JERSEY Restful web-services. I wants to Audit the user operations on add,modify,delete etc in the UI while interacting with the hibernate.

I have gone through some posts , Some suggests JPA API for hibernate auditing, some suggests Spring DATA to achieve it. I Wanted the audit data to be shown up when user interacts with the system as well as arranging it in the back-end also.

Help me from the best architecture perceptive,flow or road-map to achieve it and also give me some learning tutorials.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By _audit_, do you mean that you want another table or set of tables that tracks the adds, updates, and deletes of various entities in your application?

Comment: Set of tables already has some fields to audit.. how can I proceed with it and how can I show the user interaction in the front end like timeline....

Comment: Please see my answer below.  If that doesn't answer your question, you need to update your question and be a bit more explicit on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that by *auditing* you mean to be able track the change history that is made to entity rows at the database level, then yes Hibernate has an extension called Hibernate Envers that does this for you.

You can find documentation on Envers [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers)

The jist is that you simply need to annotate your entities with `@Audited` either at the class level or on a per property level, supply a few configuration parameters at the time you construct either your `EntityManagerFactory` or `SessionFactory` and make sure you have the appropriate tables created in your database.

Once the revision tracking has started, you can then easily query for audit changes by using the `org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader` interface.  See the documentation for how to obtain this.